# How to disallow users from changing their emails?

Tags: users, emails, advertising

I need this because it makes life a bit more difficult for 'professional' spammers who just change their emails after logging in, so that the can use that very email for the next registration, after being blocked.

Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either force users to [confirm email change](http://drupal.org/project/email_confirm) or [protect the email field](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) from changes.
Both modules have D6/7 versions. Second module can lock password and some other fields as well.

Comment: Great, as usual Drupal community offers more than you expect. That's partly why I love Drupal. Thanks mate.

Comment: I prefered 'email confirm' as a better solution but for some reason it did not install, neither through GUI nor drush. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new module which is made to handle this situation perfectly.

The module [User Account Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/useraccount_permissions) add the following new permissions for user accounts:

1. edit own user account
2. edit own email address
3. edit other user's email address
4. change own password
5. change other user's password

Answer (score 0):

Or try to use [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module (D6 or D7). set custom permission to allow create but disallow to edit own field..

Comment: I don't think that works for the e-mail address, it doesn't show up in the field list to be edited like other fields.

Comment: The module `Field Permissions` works fine with Drupal 8 but you could hide only custom fields. `User protect`works fin on D8 to hide user name, email, etc.